# I tried to install jupyter notebook with Anaconda and it shows up an error

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

When I try to launch it through the Anaconda Navigator it just starts nothing. After that, i tried to install it through the Anaconda Prompt. But it shows that error:

```
InvalidArchiveError("Error with archive C:\\Users\\User Name\\.conda\\pkgs\\python_abi-3.8-1_cp38.tar.bz2.  You probably need to delete and re-download or re-create this file.  Message from libarchive was:\n\nFailed to open 'C:\\Users\\User Name\\.conda\\pkgs\\python_abi-3.8-1_cp38.tar.bz2'")
InvalidArchiveError("Error with archive C:\\Users\\User Name\\.conda\\pkgs\\conda-4.8.3-py38h32f6830_2.tar.bz2.  You probably need to delete and re-download or re-create this file.  Message from libarchive was:\n\nFailed to open 'C:\\Users\\User Name\\.conda\\pkgs\\conda-4.8.3-py38h32f6830_2.tar.bz2'")
InvalidArchiveError("Error with archive C:\\Users\\User Name\\.conda\\pkgs\\openssl-1.1.1g-he774522_0.tar.bz2.  You probably need to delete and re-download or re-create this file.  Message from libarchive was:\n\nFailed to open 'C:\\Users\\User Name\\.conda\\pkgs\\openssl-1.1.1g-he774522_0.tar.bz2'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete C:\Users\User Name\.conda directory and reinstall Anaconda. Maybe those files was corrupted during installation, and the best recommendation is to delete everything related to the previous installation.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by myself, I just start it over the conda shell